# Custom GridAdapter with 2 columns doesn't works

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview, android-gridlayout

I want to implement a grid Adapter that receives an `ArrayList` of `Element2S`, where Element2S is a custom object with two String (Element2S(String a, String b)

The GridAdapter should use the `Element2S` `ArrayList` to populate the Grid.
the first `String` of `Element2S` object should be the first column element, the second `String` of `Element2S` the second element

My GridAdapter is:

```
public class GridViewAdapterC2 extends BaseAdapter {

        private ArrayList<Element2S> itemList;
        private Activity activity;

        public GridViewAdapterC2(Activity activity,
                ArrayList<Element2S> itemList) {
            super();
            this.itemList = itemList;
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return itemList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Element2S getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return itemList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        public static class ViewHolder {
            public TextView txtViewColumn1;
            public TextView txtViewColumn2;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ViewHolder view;
            LayoutInflater inflator = activity.getLayoutInflater();

            if (convertView == null) {
                view = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.grid_row_2c, null);

                view.txtViewColumn1 = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.col1);
                view.txtViewColumn2 = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.col2);

                convertView.setTag(view);
            } else {
                view = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            String textCoilumn1 = itemList.get(position).getA();
            String textCoilumn2 = itemList.get(position).getB();
            view.txtViewColumn1.setText(textCoilumn1);
            view.txtViewColumn2.setText(textCoilumn2);

            return convertView;
        }

    }
```

Unfortunately when in the main I try to use this adapter with

```
gridAdapter = new GridViewAdapterC2(this, myItemArrayList);
mygrid= (GridView) findViewById(R.id.myGridView);
mygrid.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
```

The result is wrong.

My gridRow layout is

```
<TableLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <TableRow android:layout_gravity="left">

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/col1"
      android:layout_width="50dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="left"
      android:gravity="left|start"
      android:padding="5dp"
      android:textColor="@color/light_sky"
      android:textSize="12sp" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/col2"
      android:layout_width="50dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="left"
      android:gravity="left|start"
      android:padding="5dp"
      android:textColor="@color/green_2"
      android:textSize="12sp" >
  </TextView>

 </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

The myGridView layout in the main activity is

```
<GridView
     android:id="@+id/myGridView"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
     android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
     android:gravity="center_horizontal"
     android:numColumns="2" >
</GridView>
```

I cannot figure what is wrong.

If my Elements2S arraylist is

```
 1st element2S:   (1,23a)
 2nd element2S:   (2,15b)
 3rd element2S:   (3,22c)
```

The Grid shows

```
1   2
3
```

But the right output is

```
  1   23a
  2   15b
  3   22c
```

Comment: What about it is wrong?  Describing what its doing and what you wanted is pretty much necessary to help.

Comment: Just to double check-  is the problem that it shows 1 and 2 on the same row, but both texts are shown (so it looks like 1  23a  2  15b)?  Or is the B string not showing?  In the first case, your problem is you need a listview, not a gridview.  In the second, I'd wonder if your getB function was returning null or an empty string.

Comment: @GabeSechan the    String textCoilumn1 = itemList.get(position).getA();
            String textCoilumn2 = itemList.get(position).getB(); get the right values, I cannot understand why the final result is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the ListView is better than GridView in this situation.

And I think the LinearLayout is better than TableLayout.

Your output is wrong because some region of your grid's cell is covered by others. Try to resize your cell and grid.